# trouble download npm package

Tags: api, npm, installation, yarnpkg

Trying to download the dominos api package but keep getting this error. I have tried downloading the .NET framework 2.0 SDK but it stil isnt letting me download this. What am I missing?

```
$ npm i dominos

> node-expat@2.3.16 install C:\Users\engqu\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\engqu\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Users\engqu\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\..\..\..\deps\libexpat\version.c
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\engqu\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-expat\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\engqu\Desktop\app\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\engqu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-29T08_12_30_456Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to install windows-build-tools? To install you need (as administrator in console):

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: same problem here, installing windows-build tools did not help though, node v14.16.1, npm 7.9.0